# Cannot implicitly convert type System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult to System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to update an EDMX Stored Procedure and I am getting this error:

Cannot implicitly convert type `System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult<X>` to `System.Data.Objects.ObjectResult<X>`

I am using Visual Studio 2012.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I had the error and none of these solutions worked (I was already using `System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects`, it was also in the `context.tt`, etc).

I eventually realised the problem lay between the keyboard and the chair. The stored proc finished with a select, but I was trying:

```
MyStoredProc_Result r = dbcontext.MyStoredPoc();
```

Instead of

```
MyStoredProc_Result r = dbcontext.MyStoredPoc().FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: you are saving my time as I am not follow above instruction

Comment: a 'more perfect' answer.

Answer (score 12):

Open the `context.tt` file in XML mode 
and change

```
using System.Data.Objects;
```

to

```
using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
```

Comment: This worked for me. I'm not sure why Entity Framework doesn't handle this for me when I update my store procedure result structure.

Comment: @Sachin : perfect answer

Comment: See answer from @SteveCav for 'best solution'...doesn't call on you to edit generated files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade to the new Entity Framework 6 runtime.

Right-click on your project and select `Manage NuGet Packages...`
Under the `Online` tab select `EntityFramework` and click `Install`
Note: If a previous version of the EntityFramework NuGet package was installed this will upgrade it to EF6.
Alternatively, you can run the following command from Package Manager Console:

```
PM> Install-Package EntityFramework
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/upgradeEF6

Comment: is this the answer of your question?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just cleaned up my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Either use VS 2013 or download the new [Entity Framework 6 Tools for Visual Studio 2012](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40762).

Answer (score 0):

You only have to change "using System.Data.Objects" to "using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It's usually a good idea to give a little explanation in answer to a question, as well as the correct response.