# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult<>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<>'

Tags: c#, asp.net, edmx

I am trying to update an EDMX Stored Procedure and I am getting this error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectResult to
>   System.Collections.Generic.List

I am using Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: Did you try [this way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24786172/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-system-data-entity-core-objects-objectresult-to-s) ?

Comment: Not need to upgrade. it is already up gradable.

Comment: It's a duplicate question of stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24786172/cannot-implicitly-convert-type-system-data-entity-core-objects-objectresult-to-s

Comment: This is not duplicate. @Kushalvora. please check both question.

Answer (score 8):

ObjectResult is an enumerable so you can use the ToList Method.

example:

```
return myEntities.sp_Get(param1, param2).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you trying to enumerate the data more than once 
Because I suggest That you use of the "for-each" and then again with the ".To-List()" for each items.